# Facebook SMS message from a non-Facebook number

Tags: facebook

I was wondering how could someone intercept a message. Last week, I was recovering my Facebook password and I received the code from another number of some operator company in my country and not from Facebook. Many people notice the same thing happening to them.

So I was wondering how could local number send me my Facebook account recovery code?

Comment: is my edit what you meant to say?